# RxJava how to handle Error without Quit flow

Tags: error-handling, rx-java2

My scenario is like this:
During a flow ,if there is an error happened during an element processing (in this example element is "three"), I still want keep processing the others.

In this example:  I want to print "1,2,4,5" however, it just print "1 ,2".

```
   Observable<String> numbers = Observable.just("1", "2", "three", "4", "5");
    numbers.map(v->{
                return  Integer.parseInt(v);
            }).onErrorResumeNext(error->{return Observable.just(-1);})
            .filter(v-> {
                System.out.println("filter value smaller than 0");
                return  v>0;
            })
            .subscribe(s -> {

                System.out.println(s);
            });
}
```

I checked doc, "onErrorResumeNext" will instead relinquish control to the Observable returned from resumeFunction.

Is there way to print "1,2,4,5"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow stops because there is a crash in `map`. The only way to avoid the flow being stopped is to not let `map` crash in your example. Put the `parseInt` into a try-catch and return -1 from the catch part.

```java
Observable<String> numbers = Observable.just("1", "2", "three", "4", "5");

numbers.map(v -> {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(v);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { // <--------------------------------------
        return -1;
    }
})
.filter(v -> {
    System.out.println("filter value smaller than 0");
    return  v > 0;
})
.subscribe(s -> {
    System.out.println(s);
});
```